# how to stop custom Messagebox from closing windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have two redio button(rb1 and rb) and a text box in custom messagebox and I want to stop custom messagebox from closing if any option is not selected.

```
box.Dismissed += (s, e1) =>
        {
            if (e1.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton)
            {
                if(rb.IsChecked.Value)
                {


                }
                else if(rb1.IsChecked.Value)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select the Option");
                   // I WANT TO STOP CLOSING CUSTOM BOX HERE IF ANY OPTION IS NOT SELECTED
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: Is the `MessageBox` a `Form`? If so, you can subscribe to `FormClosing` event and there you can use the event args to prevent the form from closing, just like this: `e.Cancel = true;` (where `e` is the `EventArgs` variable

Comment: Yes bro it has dissming event ... and it works for me .. Thanks a lot .. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer thanks to @android joker ..

```
 box.Dismissing += (s, e1) =>
            {
                e1.Cancel = true;
            };
```